# Does MATLAB use "0" to represent infinitely-many solutions?

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math

MATLAB simulates `solve(a==a)` and returns 0. The solution should have been infinitely many (the solution should have looked like `a=a`) but it simulates the solution equal to zero which is incorrect. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3):

Zero *is* a correct solution for `a`: it's the "simplest" one. By default, [`solve`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/solve.html) will just return one solution for a case with infinitely many, and that one solution happened to be zero here. However, you can get a set of parameterized solutions by setting the [`'ReturnConditions'`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/solve.html#buezrr6-ReturnConditions) flag to `true`. For the above example, you would get:

```
>> syms a
>> [sol, params, conds] = solve(a == a, 'ReturnConditions', true)

sol =

z

params =

z

conds =

TRUE
```

The solution is just a parameter `z` with no restrictions (i.e. it can be any value).